# how to parse data using ASIHttp request?

Tags: iphone

I am using webservices.I am sending request from the iphone and fetch the data.I am using http request.But i want to use ASIhttprequest so how it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the `ASIS3Request` class for details on how to subclass `ASIHTTPRequest` and perform your own tasks before or after the request is complete. Your own subclass will look something like this:

```
@interface MyFancySubclass : ASIHTTPRequest {}
@end

@implementation MyFancySubclass

- (void) main {
  // Perform pre-request initialisation here
  [super main];
}

- (void) requestFinished {
  // Parse [self responseString] or [self responseData] here
  [super requestFinished];
}

- (void) failWithError:(NSError*)theError {
  // Handle errors here
  [super failWithError:theError];
}

@end
```

If you add your `MyFancySubclass` instances to an `ASINetworkQueue`, the parsing will be done off the main thread.